# OpenCV capabilities

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection, sift

As I didn't found answer in code samples and documentation ( maybe it's because I'm using `SIFT` which is `nonfree` ) I have a question about OpenCV capabilities.

I have small set of images ( 50 ). For every image I compute `KeyPoint` ( `SIFT` detector ) and extract descriptor value. Then 200 ( unique ) of all are selected to create descriptor dictionary.

Aim is to describe every image using only this 200 descriptors ( every original descriptor in image must be replaced with the nearest ( euclidean ) descriptor from dictionary ). To keep thing clear -> I'm looking for mechanism which will be able to create map like this (`OriginalImageDescriptor`, `DictionaryDescriptor` ) for EVERY `OriginalImageDescriptor` in image.

I considered using `DescriptorMatcher` but I'm not sure it is exactly what I want because in [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_description/feature_description.html) example I can see `KeyPoint`s which aren't connected to other `KeyPoint` - does `DescriptorMatcher` match every descriptor from trainImage to some descriptor in queryImage?

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.8

Thanks!

Comment: Please see the [info](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/drawing_function_of_keypoints_and_matches.html?highlight=drawmatches#drawmatches) first. There is a flag there for what to draw

Answer (score 0):

See the below example carefully that will help you to understand better:

I have taken this example from opencv's **[SURF_Homography](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html)** and modified a bit so that you can easily use it. Here you see the matcher has **good_matches[i].queryIdx** and **good_matches[i].trainIdx**. These two are the corresponding matching pairs. Here FlannMatcher is used. You can choose any other preferred matcher.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

  Mat img_object = imread( "image1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
  Mat img_scene = imread( "image2.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );

  if( !img_object.data || !img_scene.data )
  { std::cout<< " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1; }

  //-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
  int minHessian = 400;

  SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );

  std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object, keypoints_scene;

  detector.detect( img_object, keypoints_object );
  detector.detect( img_scene, keypoints_scene );

  //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
  SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

  Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;

  extractor.compute( img_object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object );
  extractor.compute( img_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene );

  //-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
  FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
  std::vector< DMatch > matches;
  matcher.match( descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches );

  double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

  //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
  for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ )
  { double dist = matches[i].distance;
    if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
    if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
  }

  printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist );
  printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist );

  //-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
  std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

  for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ )
  { if( matches[i].distance < 3*min_dist )
    { good_matches.push_back( matches[i]); }
  }

  Mat img_matches;
  drawMatches( img_object, keypoints_object, img_scene, keypoints_scene,
               good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
               vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );


  //-- Localize the object from img_1 in img_2
  std::vector<Point2f> obj;
  std::vector<Point2f> scene;

  for( size_t i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
  {
    //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
    obj.push_back( keypoints_object[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
    scene.push_back( keypoints_scene[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
  }

  Mat H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );

  //-- Get the corners from the image_1 ( the object to be "detected" )
  std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);
  obj_corners[0] = Point(0,0); obj_corners[1] = Point( img_object.cols, 0 );
  obj_corners[2] = Point( img_object.cols, img_object.rows ); obj_corners[3] = Point( 0, img_object.rows );
  std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);

  perspectiveTransform( obj_corners, scene_corners, H);


  //-- Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene - image_2 )
  Point2f offset( (float)img_object.cols, 0);
  line( img_matches, scene_corners[0] + offset, scene_corners[1] + offset, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4 );
  line( img_matches, scene_corners[1] + offset, scene_corners[2] + offset, Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
  line( img_matches, scene_corners[2] + offset, scene_corners[3] + offset, Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
  line( img_matches, scene_corners[3] + offset, scene_corners[0] + offset, Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );

  //-- Show detected matches
  imshow( "Good Matches & Object detection", img_matches );

  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm looking for something else. I just looking for some mechanism which will be able to tell me ( for each descriptor in image ) which descriptor from my dictionary is the nearset to descriptor in image. It's something like map -> (`OriginalDescriptor` ; `NearestDictionaryDescriptor`). And i have to find `NearestDictionaryDescriptor` for EVERY `OriginalDescriptor`.
PS. Maybe I just didn't understand Your post. If so, please correct me.

Comment: Suppose you have one dictionary of descriptor is prepared and now you want to search best match among your dictionary. You can count the number of good matches with the list and the max count is the best match among the descriptor dictionary. You can use above example to count good feature count